# Testing several exceptions with same expected exception

Tags: phpunit

I'm trying to test, among others, the constructor of my class. It expects exactly one parameter which has to be a string. So I wrote this test:

```
class categoryTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

  public function testConstructor() {

    $this->setExpectedException('Exception', 'Unknown data type.');
    $objCategory = new category(1);

    $this->setExpectedException('Exception', 'Unknown data type.');
    $objCategory = new category(-500);

    $this->setExpectedException('Exception', 'Unknown data type.');
    $objCategory = new category(true);

    $this->setExpectedException('Exception', 'Unknown data type.');
    $objCategory = new category(array());

    ...

  }

  public function testNextMethod() {

  }

}
```

As you can see, I expect each time the same exception.

This works very well, so it seems, but the script will skip to testNextMethod() after finishing

```
$this->setExpectedException('Exception', 'Unknown data type.');
$objCategory = new category(1);
```

. Do I have to write for each test an own testMethod()? Or is there any workaround?

Best regards,
muff

EDIT:

Hello Cyprian,

thank you very much for your response. I solved my problem like this:

```
class categoryTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $backupGlobals = FALSE;

    /**
      *
      * @dataProvider provider
      *
      **/
    public function testMuff($strCategory) {

      $this->setExpectedException('Exception', 'Unknown data type.');
      $objCategory = new category($strCategory);

    }

    public function provider() {

      $objHIS = new DDDBL('HIS');

      return array(array(1),
                   array(-500),
                   array(true),
                   array(array()),
                   array($objHIS)
                  );

    }

    ...

}
```

Now it works perfectly, even if I don't like the notation at all.

Comment: "Note : You should be as specific as possible when testing exceptions. Testing for classes that are too generic might lead to undesirable side-effects. Accordingly, testing for the Exception class with @expectedException or setExpectedException() is no longer permitted.". Source : https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is `DataProvider`, look here:

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers